# How to use camera on ARToolKITPlus

Tags: augmented-reality, artoolkit

Sorry for my english I'm french student. 
For a school project I have to do an augmented-reality application. I used ProCamCalib to calibrate my ps eye and my projector and ARToolKit don't use the same distortion form. So I've found ARToolKitPlus who use distorstion coefficient, the same as ProCamCalib, but it used picture and I don't find how to use a camera with it. Is there somebody who already try this?
Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ARToolKitPlus doesn't have support for camera/video input so you should used it in combination of another video library such as [DSVL](http://www.icg.tugraz.at/Members/daniel/DSVL_doc), videoInput][2](https://github.com/ofTheo/videoInput) or camera input from OpenCV.

For ARToolkit, there is a discussion on the topic (standard camera parameters to artoolkit format) in the ARToolKit mailing list:

http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/mail-archive/message-thread-00422-camera-calibration.html

Comment: Oh thanks I will watch your link. I have finish my project, for the moment I use an auto calibration done by artoolkit, it's not really accurate but better than nothing